# Socket hang up; ECONNRESET with request-promise

Tags: javascript, sockets, amazon-web-services

I'm getting a RequestError when I'm trying to programmatically send a request to an API. I'm able to do this request manually with postman just fine, but when I try to do this with Javascript it's giving me socket hang up errors. My call to STS is also working, and I'm getting my set of temporary credentials. It's the POST request to `test.com` that is giving me the error.

```
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../config');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
const aws4 = require('aws4');
const Log = require('../logging/logger');

AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.Config.correctClockSkew = true;

function getTempCredentials() {

  const sts = new AWS.STS(
    {
      apiVersion: '2011-06-15',
      accessKeyId: config.awsCreds.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: config.awsCreds.secretKey,
      region: 'us-east-1'
    }
);

  const params = {
    ExternalId: config.awsCreds.externalId,
    RoleArn: config.awsCreds.roleARN,
    RoleSessionName: config.awsCreds.roleName
  };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      sts.assumeRole(params, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
          Log.error(`Failed to get temporary credentials from AWS. Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`); // an error occurred
          reject(error);
          throw error;
        }
        else  {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
  });
}

async function preRegister(load) {

  let tempCreds;

  try {

    tempCreds = await getTempCredentials();

    let options = {
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: 'us-east-1'
    }

   let signedRequest = aws4.sign(options, {
     accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
     secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
     sessionToken: tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken
   });

   let response = await rp({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://test.com',
     headers: signedRequest.headers,
     body: load
   });

    //return response;
  } catch (error) {
    Log.error(`Failed to pre-register.  Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    throw error;
  }

}
```

And here is the exact error:

```
error: Failed to pre-register.  Error: {"name":"RequestError","message":"Error: socket hang up","cause":{"code":"ECONNRESET","path":null,"host":"test.com","port":443}
```

I've also tried adding `content-type` and `content-length` headers to my request with the same values from Postman, but that doesn't work either. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this?